# How do I compile a lua luvit script into an exe while including packages

Tags: lua, luvit

This is an example lua script that can be ran with luvit:

```lua
local discordia = require('discordia')
local client = discordia.Client()

client:on('ready', function()
    print('Logged in as '.. client.user.username)
end)

client:on('messageCreate', function(message)
    if message.content == '!ping' then
        message.channel:send('Pong!')
    end
end)

client:run('')
```

I am wondering how I can compile this lua script into an exe with all packages ( discordia for example ) included in the exe build

I tried using RTC which compiles normal lua into exe, not luvit .

RTC: https://github.com/samyeyo/rtc